# c++ Variable Sized Arrays

Tags: c++

i am working on an exercise in which:

As input:
The first line contains two space-separated integers denoting the respective values of  (the number of variable-length arrays) and  (the number of queries). 
Each line  of the  subsequent lines contains a space-separated sequence in the format k a[i]0 a[i]1 … a[i]k-1 describing the -element array located at . 
Each of the  subsequent lines contains two space-separated integers describing the respective values of  (an index in array ) and  (an index in the array referenced by ) for a query.

sample input:
2 2
3 1 5 4
5 1 2 8 9 3
0 1
1 3

For output: 
For each pair of  and  values (i.e., for each query), print a single integer denoting the element located at index  of the array referenced by . There should be a total of  lines of output.

sample out put:
5
9

And my code is:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int n=0; int q=0;
    cin>>n>>q;
    vector<vector<int>> a;
    for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
        int k;
        cin>>k;
        for(int j=0; j<k;j++){
            cin>>a[i][j];
        }
    }
for(int i=0; i<q;i++){
    int x; int y;
    cin>>x>>y;
    cout<<a[x][y]<<endl;
}
cout<<n<<q;
return 0;
```

}

But when i put input, I get an error

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `std::vector` defaults to empty. It is not valid to call `operator[]` with an expression like `a[i]` on an empty `vector`.

You need to add elements to a `vector` using functions such as `push_back` or `resize`.

Answer (score 0):

Reserve space for the vector.

```
vector<int> integers( 100 );
```

See [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) for details.